# Accept requests using smpp python

Tags: python, smpp

I need to receive messages over http, over the smpp protocol for further processing
The problem is that python libraries ask for connections to a third-party server and assume sending sms messages. I need to use smpp only to receive http requests

Has anyone ever encountered such a thing?

I installed python-smtp and aiosmpplib. python-smtp requires connection from a third-party server, and aiosmpplib returns the error: ConnectionRefusedError: `[Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 2775)`

I also installed jasmin server, but it's a bit not what I need.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.